# My sql code returns 7 rows in mysql. However when I retrieve it in php, it returns a single row. How to retrieve all data in php that sql gives

Tags: php, sql

I am a beginner and following is my sql code.

```
select temp1.service_number,temp1.serial_number, temp1.start_datetime, temp1.plate_number, text , temp1.staff_id
from (select t.service_number,t.serial_number, start_datetime, plate_number, staff_id
from trip t
where t.staff_id = 3685
and start_datetime between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-01') as temp1
left outer join 
(select r.service_number, r.serial_number, r.text
from remark r) as temp2
on temp1.service_number = temp2.service_number and temp1.serial_number = temp2.serial_number;
```

As I run it, it returns 7 row. however, when I use that code in php,

```
$querytrip = "select temp1.service_number,temp1.serial_number, temp1.start_datetime, temp1.plate_number, temp2.text from (select t.service_number,t.serial_number, start_datetime, plate_number, staff_id from trip t where t.staff_id = '$staffid' and start_datetime between '$sdate' and '$edate') as temp1 left outer join (select r.service_number, r.serial_number, r.text from remark r) as temp2 on temp1.service_number = temp2.service_number and temp1.serial_number = temp2.serial_number";
            $resulttrip = mysql_query($querytrip);
```

the count($resulttrip) returns as 1.

Please help me!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of rows, you do [`mysql_num_rows($resulttrip)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), not `count($resulttrip)`. To iterate over each row, you use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) like so:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttrip))
{
  echo $result['service_number'];
}
```

You can also use [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) rather than `mysql_fetch_assoc`,

Although you should be using the [`MySQL Improved Extension`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).